# How to check if value is in array with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there an AngularJS way of checking if a value exists in an array

```
var array1 = ["a","b","c"]
```

i'm trying to do this..

```
var array2 = ["c", "d", "e"]

angular.forEach(array2, function (a) {
    if (a /*is NOT in array1*/) {
        array1.push(a);
    } else {
        return false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 29):

You can use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which will return `-1` if it's not found or the index of the value in the array.

So in your case:

```
if (array2.indexOf(a) < 0) {
  array1.push(a);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You just need to use native [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check if value is in array or not:

```
var array2 = ["c", "d", "e"]

angular.forEach(array2, function (a) {
    if (array2.indexOf(a) === -1) {
        // a is NOT in array1
        array1.push(a);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var n = fruits.includes("Mango");
```