# AngularJs - check if value exists in array object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, javascript-objects

```
var SelectedOptionId = 957;

$scope.array = [{"957":"1269"},{"958":"1265"},{"956":"1259"},{"957":"1269"},{"947":"1267"}]
```

Is there a way of checking if a value exists in an that kind of array objects. I am using Angular and underscore.

I have tried all this -

```
if ($scope.array.indexOf(SelectedOptionId) === -1) {console.log('already exists')}
```

and

```
console.log($scope.array.hasOwnProperty(SelectedOptionId)); //returns false
```

and

```
console.log(_.has($scope.array, SelectedOptionId)); //returns false
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31775970/4323328

Comment: Note: `957` is a key and not value

Comment: yes Its a key that is being pushed in the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and check with [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator.

```
exists = $scope.array.some(function (o) {
    return SelectedOptionId in o;
});
```

Comment: I have learned more just by reading your answers than googling. Thanks for being awesome. :-)

Comment: How to do it for the values i.e.- instead of  `957` I want to do it for `1269`

Comment: for values, you need to iterate over the keys of the object, and check against, like `return Object.keys(o).some(function (k) { return o[k] === value; });`

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
function checkExists (type) {
   return $scope.array.some(function (obj) { 
    return obj === type;
  }
}

var chkval=checkExists("your value")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this. The following code should return you output array with matching results, if it exists, otherwise it will return an empty array :

```js
var array = [{"957":"1269"},{"958":"1265"},{"956":"1259"},{"957":"1269"},{"947":"1267"}];
var SelectedOptionId = 957;

var result = array.filter(
  function(item) {return item[SelectedOptionId]}
)


console.log(result);
```

For your input it returns:

```
[ { '957': '1269' }, { '957': '1269' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($scope.array[SelectedOptionId] || _.includes(_.values($scope.array, SelectedOptionId))) { }
```

That should cover both a key and a value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let selectedOptionId = "957";
let array = [{"957":"1269"},{"958":"1265"},{"956":"1259"},{"957":"1269"},{"947":"1267"}];

let filtered = array.filter(function(element){
    return Object.keys(element)[0] === selectedOptionId; 
  });

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(_.some($scope.array, function(o) { return _.has(o, "957"); }));
```

using underscore

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the `in` operator or the `hasOwnProperty` function, to check for the existence of a key in an object inside the given array.

The way you've tried using `hasOwnProperty` function didn't work because you were checking it directly on the array instead of checking against the items in the array.

Check the below code snippet.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('HomeController', DefaultController);

function DefaultController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.items = [{
    "957": "1269"
  }, {
    "958": "1265"
  }, {
    "956": "1259"
  }, {
    "957": "1269"
  }, {
    "947": "1267"
  }];

  var key = '957';
  var isExists = keyExists(key, vm.items);
  console.log('is ' + key + ' exists: ' + isExists);

  function keyExists(key, items) {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      // if (key in items[i]) {
      if (items[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="HomeController as home">
    {{home.items | json}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Different ways to do this :**

1. Using Object [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method.

**Working demo :**

```js
var SelectedOptionId = 957;

var arrayObj = [{"957":"1269"},{"958":"1265"},{"956":"1259"},{"957":"1269"},{"947":"1267"}];

function checkOption(key) {
  for(var i in arrayObj) {
    if(arrayObj[i].hasOwnProperty(key) == true) {
      return key+" exists.";
    } else {
      return key+" Not exists.";
    }
  } 
};

console.log(checkOption(SelectedOptionId)); // 957 exists.
```

2. using Array [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

**Working demo :**

```js
var SelectedOptionId = 957;

var arrayObj = [{"957":"1269"},{"958":"1265"},{"956":"1259"},{"957":"1269"},{"947":"1267"}];

var result = arrayObj.filter(function(elem) {
  return elem[SelectedOptionId]
});

if(result == '') {
console.log(SelectedOptionId+" not exists.");
} else {
console.log(SelectedOptionId+" exists.");
}
```

3. using Array [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method as suggested by [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz).

**Working demo :**

```js
var SelectedOptionId = 957;

var arrayObj = [{"957":"1269"},{"958":"1265"},{"956":"1259"},{"957":"1269"},{"947":"1267"}];

var result = arrayObj.some(function (o) {
    return SelectedOptionId in o;
});

if(result == '') {
console.log(SelectedOptionId+" not exists.");
} else {
console.log(SelectedOptionId+" exists.");
}
```